# Why am I getting "Cannot redeclare class" on Symfony2 + vagrant + moved vendors optimalization setup?

Tags: symfony, vagrant

Recently I've been working on improveing my vagrant enviroment and I've stumbled upon [Running the Symfony application on Vagrant without NFS below 100ms](http://by-examples.net/2014/12/09/symfony2-on-vagrant.html) blog post.

I've moved the `vendor` dir outside the VM shared directory, as suggested, by createing `/tmp/app/vendor` dir inside the VM and setting

```
export COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR=/tmp/app/vendor
export COMPOSER_BIN_DIR=/tmp/app/bin
export SF2_ENV=vagrant
```

enviroment variables before running `composer install`.

Now, with vendors correctly installed to another path, I've modified the `app/autoload.php` file to detect if the app is running inside the VM by looking for the SF2_ENV enviroment variable:

```
if (array_key_exists('SF2_ENV', $_SERVER) && $_SERVER['SF2_ENV'] === 'vagrant') {
    // vagrant enviroment detected
    $loader = require sys_get_temp_dir().'/app/vendor/autoload.php';
} else {
    // default
    $loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

This worked fine for one project, however on another project I kept getting the

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\MappedSuperclass\AbstractLogEntry in /var/www/public_html/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Loggable/Entity/MappedSuperclass/AbstractLogEntry.php on line 13

error when trying to initialize the app cache `php app/console cache:clear -e=prod`.

## Why was this happening?

Note: I've anwsered myself, as this is a Q&A style question (a note to my future self).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting this as a reminder to my future self or anyone else interested. The problem was becouse in the second project I used Gedmo library and in my config.yml I defined:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        entity_managers:
            default:
                filters:
                    softdeleteable:
                        class: Gedmo\SoftDeleteable\Filter\SoftDeleteableFilter
                        enabled: true
                mappings:
                    gedmo_translatable:
                        type: annotation
                        prefix: Gedmo\Translatable\Entity
                        dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Translatable/Entity"
                        alias: GedmoTranslatable
                        is_bundle: false
```

So, the problem was clearly the `%kernel.root_dir%` part, which was hardcoded.

## Solution

I've simply changed it to `%vendor_dir%` and defined this parameter in my `parameters.yml` - for production as `vendor_dir: '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor'` and for local (dev) as `vendor_dir: /tmp/app/vendor`.

Answer (score 0):

I already have problem with symfony2 project on Vagrant. But I resolve this without change location of /vendor directory.

Just disable the nfs share and locate your projects directly on /var/www

you can use this on vagrantFile :

```
    config.vm.synced_folder '.', '/vagrant', disabled: true
```

Work with your Vagrant as like you work with a remote server...

What happening when you deploying in production environment your autoload.php file ? it's not very useful to change this only for dev environment (I don't speak only for this file but general idea).

Comment: Nothing is happening in my production enviroment, becouse the `SF2_ENV` variable does not exist there. So the `if` resolves to false and executes the `else` block (which is the default behaviour).

Comment: Also the `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR` and `COMPOSER_BIN_DIR` are undefined in my production env, so composer install on my production server will install vendors in the project root dir/vendor.